# Form post warning message after upgrading jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have upgraded to jquery 1.10.2.  I am using jquery migrate and I am having the warning message "jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string"

I have not understood how I can correct that.  Can anyone help me out with the best solution of how I can remove the warning message

The javascript is as follows:

```
 function Search() {

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "html",
            url: "@Url.Action("Search")",
            data:  JSON.stringify({myModel: $("#DateFrom").val()}),
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#NewDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error)
            {
                  DisplayError(ParseErrorFromResponse(request.responseText, "Unknown error"), true);
            }
        });

 }
```

In the Controller:

```
 public PartialViewResult Search(myModel myModel)
    {
        return PartialView("SearchResult", myModel);
    }
```

ParseErrorFromResponse:

```
Function ParseErrorFromResponse(responseText, defaultError)
{
    var text = responseText.replace("<title>", "TitleStart");       
    var startIndex = text.indexOf("TitleStart");
    var endIndex = text.indexOf("TitleEnd");
    return (startIndex == -1 || endIndex == -1) ? defaultError : text.substring(startIndex + 10, endIndex);
}
```

Comment: What's ParseErrorFromResponse?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum please detailed code in edited part

Comment: Don't you try to parse JSON in success callback instead of '$("#NewDiv").html(data);' in your real sample ?

Comment: No, I don't you try to parse JSON in success callback

Comment: I tried to reproduce your sample ( expect the DiplayError code which is missing ) in a blank app  and I get no warning ? Did you try to reproduce this test case ?

Comment: Are you able to post a sample of the JSON in `#DataForm`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to send your data as `JSON`.

Where you have data: `$("#DateFrom").val()`, replace it with data: `JSON.stringify({$("#DateFrom").val()})`.

EDIT: You may need to send it as `JSON.stringify({(myModel: $("#DateFrom").val()})`.

Comment: This doesn`t help either

Comment: Check Satpal's answer, i had an extra ( in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error may be related to `""` or `false` values that used to convert to `null` in versions of jQuery prior to `1.9.0` per [**THIS PAGE**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md)

Here it the relevant excerpt including the suggested solution:

> ***JQMIGRATE: jQuery.parseJSON requires a valid JSON string***
>
> **Cause**: Before jQuery 1.9.0, the `$.parseJSON()` method allowed some
>   invalid JSON strings and returned null as a result without throwing an
>   error. This put it at odds with the JSON.parse() method. The two
>   methods are aligned as of 1.9.0 and values such as an empty string are
>   properly not considered valid by `$.parseJSON()`.
>
> **Solution**: If you want to consider values such as `""` or `false`
>   successful and treat them as null, check for them before calling
>   `$.parseJSON()`. Since falsy values such as an empty string were
>   previously returned as a null without complaint, this code will
>   suffice in most cases:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(jsonString || "null");
```

> If your own code is not
>   calling `$.parseJSON()` directly, it is probably using AJAX to retrieve
>   a JSON value from a server that is returning an empty string in the
>   content body rather than a valid JSON response such as `null` or `{}`. If
>   it isn't possible to correct the invalid JSON in the server response,
>   you can retrieve the response as text:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function( text ) {
        var json = text? $.parseJSON(text) : null;
        ...
    } 
});
```

Comment: Data is raw html. I can`t do var json = data? $.parseJSON(data) : null;

Comment: @learning is the function `Search` the only part of your application that uses a JSON method? What is the output of `console.log( $.type( $("#DateFrom").val() ) )` and `console.log( $("#DateFrom").val() )`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **content-type** attribute and do like this:

```
function Search() {

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: "@Url.Action("Search","ControllerName")",
            dataType:"html",
            data:
            {
            myModel: $("#DateFrom").val()
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#NewDiv").html(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error)
            {
                  DisplayError(ParseErrorFromResponse(request.responseText, "Unknown error"), true);
            }
        });

 }
```

and in action:

```
 public PartialViewResult Search(string myModel)
    {
        return PartialView("SearchResult", myModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're missing double quotes around key myModel in line

```
...
data:  JSON.stringify({myModel: $("#DateFrom").val()},
...
```

and not because of jquery version upgrade.try using

```
data:  JSON.stringify({"myModel": $("#DateFrom").val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.. You have to return Json as result from your Search().

```
 public JsonResult Search(myModel myModel)
 {
    return Json(result);
 }
```

and also in you Script, try like this..

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST"
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "@Url.Action("Search","ControllerName")",
        dataType: "json",
        data:  JSON.stringify({"myModel": $("#DateFrom").val()}),
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("#NewDiv").html(data);
        }
    });
```

Also check $("#DateFrom").val() is having correct value and put an

```
alert(data)
```

in success and check the returned data.

I have updated the url.